# Is there a way to provide an array value for globals in phpunit configuration.xml?

Tags: php, arrays, configuration, phpunit

According to https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html i try to set some variables for the $GLOBALS array with phpunit. This works fine when i want to assign a string value to the global variable by defining:

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <var name="NAME_OF_GLOBAL" value="VALUE_OF_GLOBAL" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

but i could not manage to provide an array to a single global variable. My problem is that i want to provide an array of files that provides the needed datasets for my DB tests and i want to avoid an CSV for this global variable.

What i want to achieve is basically this:

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <var name="NAME_OF_GLOBAL">
            <values>
                <value>file1</value>
                <value>file2</value>                    
            </values>
        </var>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

but i am not sure if and how this is possible. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you define array of values in JSON format?

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <var name="NAME_OF_GLOBAL" value="['file1', 'file2']" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

And in your tests, you get the array with json_decode($GLOBALS['NAME_OF_GLOBAL'], true)? I didn't test with this, but you can try.

Comment: Hi, thanks i think i will do it this way if there is no other solution to this.

Comment: Another way would be a serialized string that you can [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) . But in my opinion is the JSON string more readable.